# Disable nth child in select menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a select menu as such:

```
<select class="priority">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

I am using the following piece of code to disable the inputs:

```
$('[id^=yellow_]').on('click', function () {
            var priority_value =$("input:checkbox[id^='yellow_box_']:checked").length;
            $('select').children(':nth-child('> + priority_value + ')').prop('disabled', true);
        });
```

Irrespective of the priority_value, all the select menu children are getting disabled on  the click event, not just the options grater than priority_value. Why is this happening?

Comment: can you create a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Use the greater than selector

Replace

```
$('select').children(':nth-child('> + priority_value + ')').prop('disabled', true);
```

With

```
$('select').children(':gt(' + priority_value + ')').prop('disabled', true);
```

Comment: I have multiple selects on the page. Could this be the problem?

Comment: Yes it will be. Change $('select') to something more specific like a class or id selector.